# get terms that have post with custom post type between 2 values

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I have taxonomy terms for Countries and post type for Destination that have many dates for tour.
I want to get all terms that have posts width the Custom Filed (Custom field with Advanced custom field pro plugin) that have values between two values.

Example:
I have 8 tours dates(custom field) to china (post) in Asia (taxonomy term) and 2 tours dates(custom field) to England (post) in Europe (taxonomy term) between 1.6.2016 and 31.6.2016.

I want to get those two terms Asia and Europe.

Edit:

1) I need to display all tour(it post) dates in tour single page, and create taxonomy for countries.

2) I need to filter posts by dates and by taxonomy term

3) I need to create two drop down list (select) to filter. when you choose one select, the other select changes to only available. If you select India the dates select change to all available dates from all post from taxonomy India.

Comment: I'd start with a `meta_query` to get posts within those dates and then loop the posts to get the terms from the taxonomy. while you could combine with a `tax_query` it could make it more complex than you need.

Comment: but that mean that I need to query all posts from the site. it's can take long time to over all posts and get all their terms and filter that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the finish code for this:

```
<?php 

    $dates_array = array();
    $countries_array = array();
    $term_list = array();
    $current_term_list = array();

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tours', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    global $post;

    $tour_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'tours_cats' );
    $current_term_list = array();
    foreach ($tour_terms as $tour) {

        if(!array_key_exists( $tour->term_id , $term_list )) {
            $term_list[$tour->term_id] = array();
        }
        $current_term_list[] = $tour->term_id;
    }
    $tour_dates = '';
    if( have_rows('tour_dates_repeater') ):
    while ( have_rows('tour_dates_repeater') ) : the_row();
        $mydate = get_sub_field('date_start');
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $mydate);

        foreach($current_term_list as $term_dates) {
            $my_custom_date = $date->format('Ymd');
            if(!in_array($my_custom_date, $term_list[$term_dates])) {
                $term_list[$term_dates][] = $date->format('Ymd');
            }

        }
    endwhile;
    endif; //end repeater field

endwhile; wp_reset_query(); //end wp_query ?>

<?php 

echo '<select name="dest">';
    foreach($term_list as $key => $value) {
        $values = '';
        foreach($value as $date) {
            $values .= '.date_'. $date .' ';
        }
        $term_name = get_term_by('id', $key, 'tours_cats')->name;
        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" class="'. $values .'">'. $term_name .'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';


$termslist = array();
foreach($term_list as $key => $value) {
    $termslist = $termslist + $value;
}
$flip = array_flip($termslist);


foreach($flip as $key_var => $var) {
    $flip[$key_var] = array();
}

foreach($flip as $key_var => $var) {

    foreach($term_list as $key => $value) {

        if(in_array($key_var, $value)) {
            $flip[$key_var][] = $key;
        }
    }

}

echo '<select name="dest">';
    foreach($flip as $key => $date_select) {
        $values = '';
        foreach($date_select as $termid) {
            $values .= '.termid_'. $termid .' ';
        }
        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" class="'. $values .'">'. $key .'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: you should really be storing your dates as y/m/d and doing a `meta_query` on the date rather than querying for everything and filtering in PHP. if you eventually have lots of tours, you may reach a point where it no longer fits in physical memory.

Comment: but I need array of all dates. the dates is array of terms id that have those dates.
So by meta query I can't get this. I can get post, but here I need to get terms.

Comment: I would say you should rethink how you're storing that data then.

Comment: @Milo What are you think about it? How do you store those things?
1) I need to display all tour(it post) dates in tour single page, and create taxonomy for countries.
2) I need to filter posts by dates and by taxonomy term
3) I need to create two drop down list (select) to filter. when you choose one select, the other select changes to only available. If you select India the dates select change to all available dates from all post from taxonomy India.